# How to set cardinality for textfield field in custom form?

Tags: 7, entities

I just created a new custom form using hook_forms, I added all my fields, everything looks fine.

One of the field is a textfield. I wanted to allow the users to set as many values as they want.

I found the "cardinality" attribute but I could not figure how to use it.
Is it possible without creating a custom field?

Thank you